# Google Cloud S3 & rclone: Error 400: Cannot insert legacy ACL for an object when uniform bucket-level access is enabled

Tags: google-cloud-platform, amazon-s3

I'm trying to configure `rclone` to access a google cloud bucket (which happens to be managed by terra.bio. My `rclone` config reads as follows:

```
[terra]
type = google cloud storage
object_acl = private
bucket_acl = private
token = {"access_token":"XXXXX","token_type":"Bearer","refresh_token":"XXXXX","expiry":"XXXXXX"}
```

I've tried setting `authenticatedRead` and `private` but get the same result.

The error message I see is:

```
2022/08/13 18:24:44 Failed to copy: googleapi: Error 400: Cannot insert legacy ACL for an object when uniform bucket-level access is enabled. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access, invalid
```

Comment: You cannot set the ACL authenticatedRead, private, etc on Cloud Storage Objects when uniform bucket-level access is enabled. I am not familiar with terra.bio, but check if there is a way to disable setting object ACLs.

Comment: @JohnHanley you're a genius, thanks! After searching on what you said I found the solution here: https://github.com/rclone/rclone/issues/3644

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution, thanks to @John Hanley in comments, is here: https://github.com/rclone/rclone/issues/3644

Either of the following solves the problem:

Set an environment variable:

```
export RCLONE_GCS_BUCKET_POLICY_ONLY=true
```

Or use the rclone param:

```
rclone --gcs-bucket-policy-only copy localfile gcp:bucket/path/
```